# How Can I Change Repeating date to one in excel?

Tags: excel-formula

I have below question:
On column A1: A16, I have some repeated dates.
On column B1:B16, I have the numbers which are assigned each one only to a date on column A. For instance, B1 to A1, B2 to A2 and etc. 
I copy column A to column C and use from Data – Remove Duplicates. 
Now, I want to have total sum of numbers which are assigned to each exact date on column D (front of column C).
I have attached an example of excel sheet. 
How can I do?

```
4/4/2015    20000000    4/4/2015    94010000
4/4/2015    9510000     4/9/2015    
4/4/2015    50000000    4/13/2015   
4/4/2015    14500000    4/14/2015   
4/9/2015    200000000   4/19/2015   
4/9/2015    200000000   4/27/2015   
4/13/2015   672716000       
4/14/2015   28448000        
4/19/2015   26168000        
4/19/2015   26168000        
4/19/2015   18568000        
4/19/2015   18568000        
4/27/2015   41368000        
4/27/2015   13500000        
4/27/2015   200000000       
4/27/2015   52926000
```

Comment: Use Data Consolidate instead of Remove Duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

**Extract Unique Items and Corresponding Totals**

Assuming that your data is located as follows:

*Dates* range `B7:B21` and *Amounts* range `C7:C21`

To extract a list of *unique* dates enter this `FormulaArray` in `E7` and copy till last record:

*(Formulas Array are entered by pressing* `[Ctrl]` *+* `[Shift]` *+* `[Enter]` *simultaneously)*

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( $B$7:$B$21, MATCH( 0, COUNTIF( $E$6:$E6, $B$7:$B$21 ), 0 ) * 1 ), "" )
```

Then to have the total amount for each date in the next column enter this formula in `F7` and copy till last record:

```
=IF( EXACT( $E7, "" ), "", SUMIF( $B$7:$B$21, $E7, $C$7:$C$21 ))
```